# Constantly showing a popup - "unfortunately, YouTube has stopped"

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, popup

I have an HTC desire 826 dual sim smartphone(Android 5.1) and a few days ago it showed a pop-up with a message saying something like "Youtube app might harm your device". So I have uninstalled youtube app (don't remember whether I did this by clicking a button in the popup or not). after that, it worked fine. but today for some reason, I have restarted my phone, and after the boot process, it shows a popup with "unfortunately, YouTube has stopped". It appeared instantly again when I click the OK button and cannot get focus to anything on the screen.(apart from 1-2 seconds)

I tried to resolve this by clearing the cache partition, reboot to the bootloader options in recovery mode, but they were gone nowhere. 
Could anyone have an idea how to get rid of this ?

Comment: I got the same problem ...same phone model..did you resolve the problem ??

Comment: check whether YouTube is still present in app list. go-to settings, apps. if you can see YouTube there, then try to clear cache and data of YouTube.

Comment: I reset the phone to factory settings, solves the problem but still getting that pop up with "Youtube app might harm your device" time to time. I suspect this may be happened again due to the HD player app, installed by the manufacturer.

Comment: Same problem. After factory reset, after few days, "unfortunately, Youtube has stopped" appeared again.